PyAutoGUIのクリックを途中で終了できるか
簡単なクリッカーツールを作っています。指定した回数、マウスを自動クリックするものです。
指定した回数クリックし終わる前に動作を終了することも可能にしたいんですが、可能なんでしょうか？keyboardライブラリを使って、シフトキーが押されると途中でも終了と言った感じです。
下記のコードでは、クリックしきってからifに入るのでもちろんダメでした。whileでクリックを繰り返すようにすると、間隔が指定できないようになるのでこちらも避けたいです。
import pyautogui
import keyboard

for l in range(1):
    pyautogui.click(clicks= 10, interval= 1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("shift"):
       print("CLICK FINISH")
       break


pyautogui.click()メソッドで回数指定するのではなく、for l in range(1):の方で回数を調節すれば良いのでは？ 各クリック間の間隔はtime.sleep(1)とかで調整するとか。 それから質問時の転記ミスでしょうか、if文の下の2行にインデントが不足しているようですが。こちらの記事が参考になるかも。Why is KeyboardInterrupt not working for Python pyautogui script? Alternative way to exit program/loop?, Stop mouse event when pressing key, How to stop or pause pyautogui at any moment that I want?

ありがとうございます！sleepという手がありました！
インデントについて、転記をミスしておりました、修正いたします！

そもそも、現状のコードで for ループは何をしているのでしょうか？ (特に意味が無さそうに見えます)

おっしゃる通りです「break」という動きがやりたかったので、forで書き始めたものの、ループさせる気はなかったのでrange(1)とかにしてみましたが、（分かってはいたんですが）if文はクリックの処理が終わってからの実行となるため、意味がありませんでした。適当に質問を投げすぎました。
